# World Types, There many types of worlds, Can someone please name some types of worlds there are? Via movie or book

Tags: future

I am looking for world type ideas here. What type of world is Blade Runner for example?  Worlds names like dystopian world or cyber punk world.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Merk. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. As is, this question is unclear how it relates to worldbuilding and appears to be asking for a basic list of "world types" and is on track to being put on hold as _unclear what you're asking_. You can [edit] your post to better define your query. If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986).

Comment: I think I am looking for names of world types, example dystopian world or post apocalyptic.

Comment: If memory serves me there is a community policy about *not* answering questions of the "what do I name something" type.

Comment: @StephenG That rule covers questions of the type "Please help me name this thing I made". This question seems to just be asking for a list of various settings (steampunk, cyberpunk, medieval fantasy, etc.), which is probably off-topic in some other way, but not a "help me name something" question.

Comment: There are a lot of types and sub types of world, yoou can create your own, but a few popular exemples would be Cyberpunk(Akira, Ghost in the shell, Blade Runner), Steampunk(Bioshock,Atack on Titan),Gaspunk,Nuclearpunk(Fallout Series),Sword and Magic(Lord of the Rings,Dungeons and Dragons),Space Odissey(Star wars,Star Trekk),etc.

Comment: @StephenG Yes you are 100 percent correct.

Comment: You are being mislead by using the wrong terminology. Most sources do not refer to what you are looking for as types of worlds, but rather [(sub)genres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre_fiction) of [speculative fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction). Start with the two Wikipedia articles and follow the links.

Comment: Fantasy, sci-fi, historical and real Worlds.

Answer (score 2):

The world of *Blade Runner* is an alternative present. After all, the events of the movie, made in 1982, took place in the far future time of 2019.

This would be the present except our present has a suspicious lack of aerocars, replicant androids, and colonies on other planets. Even the architecture and cityscapes aren't the same.

A present time that isn't our present time, so it's an alternative present.

Comment: can you rattle off 9 other "world types" seen in fiction?

Comment: @Willk Yes. Why do you ask? That way I rattle away in what might be a helpful manner.

Comment: Well, the OP requested world categories, and I would like to read them too, and I figured you could do it.  Also, now also you have an answer up before the closer crew got this questioned closed so you are the only one who can.

Comment: When the first Blade Runner was released it wasn't 2019 yet, so it cannot be alternate present, I think the better definition would be a cyberpunk themed world.

Comment: Thank you all. I think Cyber is what i am looking for. I also wanted to know what other world types are there?  The closer crew is crazy. My question is straight to the point.

Comment: @CaioNogueira It is an alternative present -- now. Next year it will be an alternative past, & in 1982 it was an alternative future. Cyberpunk was more virtual reality focused, but intelligent robots, the so-called replicants, does come close. It can also be classified as a dystopian future (from 1982's perspective). There are multiple identifiable science-fictional strands running through its story. Future *noir* also works. Perhaps thematically better than other narrower terms.

Comment: @Willk Kind of you to suggest that. World types depend on the degrees of difference in various imagined fictional worlds. This depends on much and many degrees of difference. Also, on the fictional mode involved. The factors can be historical, cultural, social, political, philosophical. scientific, technological, and sometimes purely arbitrary. How they differ depends on genre traditions and authorial aims.